# IF statement returning FALSE/TRUE instead of a number value

Tags: google-sheets

Hello I am having trouble getting this formula to work. It keeps returning false.
My "I" column retains a text value of either "PUSH", "WIN", "LOSS".
Depending on that value i want to be able to calculate the units.
Column "E" retains the units value which correspond with the bet value of Column "F".
Column "H" is the column I am trying to calculate the win/loss function.

=IF(I10 = "WIN", H10=(G10/200), IF(I10 = "LOSS", H10=(E10*(-1)), IF(I10 = "PUSH", H10=0)) )

[Screenshot of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9WoX.png)

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

[IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364) parameters are as follows: `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)`. This means that:

- If `logical_expression` returns `TRUE`, current cell is set to `value_if_true`.
- If `logical_expression` returns `FALSE`, current cell is set to `value_if_false`.

In this case, you are assigning `value_if_true` to a condition (`H10=(G10/200)`), and `value_if_false` to one of these possible conditions (`H10=(E10*(-1))`, `H10=0`). Conditions return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, and that explains the behaviour you are getting.

I think your confusion comes from the belief that you need to specify which cell you want to write the value to, when IF already writes to the current cell (the cell where the formula is written).

#### Solution:

`=IF(I10 = "WIN", G10/200, IF(I10 = "LOSS", E10*(-1), IF(I10 = "PUSH", 0) ))`

#### Reference:

- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)